# Child of any element under class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to set all paragraphs to color green regardless of what element the parent is and also regardless of the number of parents and sub-parents, as long as they are inside the class "main_class".

```html
<style>
     .main_class > (?) > p { color: green; }
</style>

<div class="main_class">
    <p> Test </p>
    <div>
        <p> Test </p>
    </div>
    <td> Test </p>
    <div>
        <div>
            <td>
                <p> Test </p>
            </td>
        </div<
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <td> Test </p> is misaligned tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you are using will only select the `p` which are directly nested under `.main_class`

so use the following selector. This will select any `p` element at any nested level as long as it's nested under `.main_class`

```
.main_class p { 
  color: green; 
}
```

> Would also like to add here that your Markup is invalid. You are
>   mixing up the `td`, `div` & `p`. For more info, refer to [W3C HTML
>   Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to validate your markup.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply to add css as following:-

```css
.main_class p {color: green;}
```